# Simplification of Complex Number.

Tags: complex-numbers

I would appreciate any hints for the following problem:

Given that

$z=\dfrac{1-\cos4\theta+i\sin4\theta}{\sin2\theta+2i\cos^2\theta}$

show that $\vert z\vert=2\sin\theta$ and arg $z=\theta$

Update:

Using John's suggestion I now have

$\dfrac{1-\cos4\theta+i\sin4\theta}{\sin2\theta+2i\cos^2\theta}=\dfrac{1-(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^4}{2\sin\theta\cos\theta+2i\cos^2\theta}=\dfrac{1-(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^4}{2\cos\theta(\sin\theta+i\cos\theta)}$

Comment: You may have dropped a minus sign in the numerator?  $$1 - \cos 4\theta + i \sin 4\theta = 1 - (\cos 4\theta - i \sin 4\theta) = 1 - (\cos \theta - i \sin \theta)^4$$

Comment: the result does not seem to be right. take $\theta = \pi/2,$ then $z = \dfrac{1 - \cos 2 \pi + i \sin 2 \pi}{\sin \pi + 2i \cos^2 \pi/2} = 0  \neq 2 \sin (\pi/2)e^{i\pi/2}.$  in fact $|z| = 2\cos \theta, arg z = -\theta$

Answer (score 1):

First I'd use some trig identities to get everything in terms of $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ (or perhaps $\sin 2\theta$ and $\cos 2\theta$).

Next I'd make the denominator purely real by multiplying top and bottom by the complex conjugate of the denominator.

From there you can split the fraction easily into a purely real and purely imaginary part, and go from there.

There may be easier ways to do it, but this will get you there.  Maybe try using Euler's identity; as a start, the numerator is also $1 - e^{-4i\theta}.$

Comment: could you check my progress?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the facts that $\left|\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right|=\frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|}$ and $\mathrm{arg}\left(\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right)=\mathrm{arg}(z_1)-\mathrm{arg}(z_2)$.

Comment: Can you show more steps using this approach?

Comment: 1) Find the modulus and argument of the complex number in the numerator.  You will need to use some trig identities.

2) Find the modulus and argument of the complex number in the denominator.  Trig identities here, too.

3) Find the modulus and argument of the quotient using the formulas above.

Answer (score 0):

1 - cos4θ = sin(2θ)^2+cos(2θ)^2 - cos(2θ)^2 + sin(2θ)^2 = 2sin(2θ)^2
sin4θ = 2sin2θcos2θ

from here follows:1 - cos4θ + isin4θ = 2sin2θ(sin2θ+icos2θ) = 4sinθcosθ(sin2θ+icos2θ)

when you do division by 2cosθ(sinθ+icosθ) you are left with 2sinθ(sin2θ+icos2θ)/(sinθ+icosθ)

that means |z|=2sinθ and arg z=θ since  sin2θ+icos2θ has rho = 1 and arg =2θ a sinθ+icosθ has rho = 1 and arg =θ. 2θ - θ = θ

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming $0 \le \theta < \pi/2$. Since \begin{align}(1 - \cos 4\theta) + i\sin 4\theta &= 2\sin^2 2\theta + i(2\sin 2\theta \cos 2\theta)\\
& = 2\sin 2\theta (\sin 2\theta + i \cos 2\theta)\\
& = 2\sin 2\theta e^{i(2\theta - \pi/2)}
\end{align}

and

$$\sin 2\theta + 2i\cos^2 \theta = 2\sin \theta \cos \theta + 2i\cos^2 \theta = 2\cos \theta(\sin \theta + i \cos \theta) = 2\cos \theta e^{i(\theta- \pi/2)}$$

we have $$z = \frac{2\sin 2\theta}{2\cos \theta}e^{i[(2\theta - \pi/2) - (\theta - \pi/2)]} = (2\sin \theta) e^{i\theta}$$ Therefore $|z| = 2\sin \theta$ and $\arg z = \theta$.